# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'guild') || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { EmbedBuilder, TextInputStyle, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('experemental')
    .setDescription('Apply for Experemental Programme.'),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
      .setCustomId('modal')
      .setTitle(`Apply for Experimental Programme`);

    const questionModal = new TextInputBuilder()
      .setCustomId('questionModal')
      .setLabel('Your Discord Username.')
      .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

    const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(questionModal);

    modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);

    await interaction.showModal(modal);

    const modalResponse = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
      filter: (i) =>
        i.customId === 'modal' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
      time: 0,
    });

    const description = modalResponse.fields.getTextInputValue('questionModal');

    // Get the server and channel IDs from the options
    const serverId = interaction.options.get('845347382206922782');
    const channelId = interaction.options.get('1103660151040397394');

    // Fetch the server and channel objects
    const server = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(serverId);
    const channel = server.channels.cache.get(channelId);

    // Send the embed message to the channel
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle('Hello!')
      .setDescription(`Hello! ${description}`);
    await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
  },
};
```

I want to send an embed message to a specific channel and server that the bot has already joined. The problem is that in this line `const server = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(serverId);` it return my this error in the console:

```
C:\---\---\---\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildManager.js:264
    const id = this.resolveId(options) ?? this.resolveId(options.guild);
                                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'guild')
```

Any answer is accepted. Thank you in advance.

### NOTE:

Both of these articles [1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74201050/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-guild-discord-js-v14) and [2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245416/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-guild) doesn't seem to solve my case!

Comment: What intents have you initialized with the bot? You are likely missing the `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds`

Comment: @ThatsLiamS These are my intents:
`const { Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages, GuildVoiceStates } = GatewayIntentBits;`
&
`intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages, GuildVoiceStates],`

Comment: What NodeJS / DiscordJS / DiscordJS Builders are you on? The latest?

Comment: @ThatsLiam My versions: `npm: '9.6.3',
  node: '18.12.1', "@discordjs/builders": "^1.6.1", "discord.js": "^14.9.0",`

Comment: Looking at your code. `const serverId = interaction.options.get('845347382206922782');` is that the ID of the server you want? You don't have options on the slash command to get (only a name and description set at the top) ? Is this meant to be from the interaction / the modal or hard coded?

Comment: It's meant to be hard coded of course.

Comment: Replace the four lines with ```const server = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch("845347382206922782");
    const channel = server.channels.cache.get("1103660151040397394");```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be coming from these lines. The SlashCommandBuilder at the top of the file has no options, only a name and a description hence there are no options to fetch. Hence `serverId` is't defined, and when passed through `fetch`, it throws an error.

```js
// Get the server and channel IDs from the options
const serverId = interaction.options.get('845347382206922782'); // not a thing
const channelId = interaction.options.get('1103660151040397394'); // not a thing

// Fetch the server and channel objects
const server = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(serverId); // serverId undefined
const channel = server.channels.cache.get(channelId); // channelId undefined
```

Remove the middle ground, and enter the hardcoded data straight into the `guilds.fetch` and `cache.get`. For example:

```
const server = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch("845347382206922782");
const channel = server.channels.cache.get("1103660151040397394");
```

Hope this helps!